# Baffled by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, coldfusion, url-rewriting

Apologies but my knowledge of url rewriting is limited!

I have setup urls to reqwrite for each of our categories in our ecommerce store.

I have a feeling I am setting this up an extremely long winded way, would someone mind checking i have done this the right way?

Ideally we would like just the word category- for all our categories at all levels, not tools- list- and timber- but i couldn't figure out a way to do this without the redirect causing errors.

here is our htaccess-:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.xxxx.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxxx.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule Product-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ /Details.cfm?Name=$1&ProdID=$2&category=$3&secondary=$4&third=$5&brand=$6 [NC]
RewriteRule Brands-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ /Results.cfm?bname=$1&brand=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule Tools-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ /subcat.cfm?category=$2-$1&secondary=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule Timber-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ /subsubcat.cfm?category=56&secondary=$2-$1 [NC]
RewriteRule Category-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ /subsubcat.cfm?category=$3&secondary=$2-$1
RewriteRule List-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ /Results.cfm?category=$1&secondary=$3&third=$2-$4

RewriteRule ([^\s]+)\s(.*) $1-$2 [NC,LP,R=301] 
*//RewriteBase /
*//RewriteRule ^(.*)%20(.*)$ $1-$2 [LP,R=301,L]

RewriteRule Festool-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ /SubCat.cfm?category=$1&secondary=$2
RewriteRule Lie_nielsen-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ /SubCat.cfm?category=$1&secondary=$2
```

Any help would be GREAT!!

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's better to let the application layer take care of URL dispatching, so you web server just redirects everything to the particular file and ColdFusion will do the rest (by matching rules for example). Have a look at ColdCourse package at  http://coldcourse.riaforge.org/ to avoid reinventing the wheel.
In that case your .htaccess file could be as simple as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.cfm?course=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help Jura, I will read this tonight and give it a try tomorrow. I will let you know what happens!